# Solenoid valves in series or parallel?

Tags: switches, solid-state-relay, solenoid, solenoid-valve

I already have the main solution and dosing solution tanks hooked up to each other, with solenoid valve S1 controlled by the liquid level switch through the DC power supply and DC/AC SSR (see image), and it works great. However, I would like to add a third tank and a second solenoid valve S2 so that solenoid S2 turns on/off whenever solenoid S1 turns on/off. Is there any reason that installing them in-series like this would be problematic? Would it be better to install them in-parallel? Or should I just install an additional liquid level switch, 24 VDC power supply, and SSR to control the new solenoid S2 separately?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the valves are designed to be operated on 120 VAC, you should connect them in parallel.  If they will always be operated together, they can be controlled by the same SSR. (If you connect the solenoids in series, each solenoid will only get 60 volts, and will probably not work.)

If you want to control the valves separately, you shouldn't need another 24 volt supply - you can connect another switch and SSR to the power supply you already have.